# Change format of chapter

Tags: formatting, chapters, titlesec, changes

How to change format of chapter like this photo, please?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}% juts to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{4ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filright}
[\vspace{2ex}%
\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In order to suggest how to change X to produce Y, we need to have X and not just a picture of Y. Please provide a minimal working example demonstrating your current chapter configuration. The answer depends very much on such things as your class and any packages or code you are already using to modify the format of chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: modified chapter]

Obviously you may wish to tweak the sizing etc. I've assumed that you may have a double-digit number of chapter and that it would be good for the line and title on the right to occupy the same width regardless. If you have fewer than 10 chapters, you might consider changing `99` to `9` in the code which calculates the relevant widths.

Note that I'm personally aversive to `titlesec` and friends, despite their popularity and would not be likely to use this method myself. So it is good you supplied the MWE else I'd have given you likely incompatible code and caused all kinds of trouble!

## *Caveat emptor ...*

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,calc}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}% juts to generate text for the example

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newlength\chaptertitlenamewidth
  \newlength\chapternumberwidth
  \newlength\chapternumberheight
  \newlength\chaptertitlenameheight
  \newlength\chaptertitlenameraise
  \newlength\chaptertitlewidth
  \newsavebox{\chaptertitlenamebox}%
  \sbox\chaptertitlenamebox{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}}%
  \settowidth{\chaptertitlenamewidth}{\usebox{\chaptertitlenamebox}}%
  \settototalheight{\chaptertitlenameheight}{\usebox{\chaptertitlenamebox}}%
  \settowidth{\chapternumberwidth}{\bfseries\Huge 99}%
  \settototalheight{\chapternumberheight}{\bfseries\Huge 99}%
  \setlength{\chaptertitlenameraise}{\chapternumberheight-\chaptertitlenameheight}%
  \setlength{\chaptertitlewidth}{\textwidth-\chaptertitlenamewidth-\chapternumberwidth-.5em}%
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\bfseries}{\raisebox{\chaptertitlenameraise}{\usebox{\chaptertitlenamebox}}\hskip .25em\begin{minipage}[b]{\chapternumberwidth}\filcenter\Huge\thechapter\end{minipage}}{0pt}{%
  \hskip .25em\begin{minipage}[b]{\chaptertitlewidth}\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{2ex}%
  }[\end{minipage}]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose this variant:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

 \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = *}{40}}%
{\filright\sffamily\parbox[b][1.6cm][t]{3.5cm}{\MakeUppercase{\large\lsstyle\chaptertitlename} \raisebox{-0.75\height}{\resizebox{!}{1.6cm}{\Huge\thechapter}}}}
{0ex}%
{\parbox[b][1.6cm]{\dimexpr\linewidth-3.5cm-1.6pt\relax}{\titlerule[1.5pt] \vspace{2ex}\vfill\endgraf\filright\bfseries\Large#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Une courte \\Introduction}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]